# Scrolling screen capture by pressing a button

Tags: windows, windows-10, scrolling, screen-capture

I need to capture a page including lines of codes or texts  and able to be scrolled. There are some applications like Snagit or ShareX but they don't work as wished. For example, snagit cannot recognize Visual Studio application thereby not showing arrow buttons. As to Sharex, it overlaps shifting scrolls thus ruining combination parts.

So, I need a application or a way that I can press a button whenever I need then it combines the pictures   one under the other.

Comment: Could you better explain your need and which pictures need to be combined?

Comment: @harrymc The pictures needed to be combined are those taken by pressing a button(s) at the time I want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware of, I've not seen any native function that can accomplish this, and discussing 3rd party applications will arguably constitute as a request for software recommendations, which is against community guidelines here.

However, since I'm here, I may as well take a shot at pointing you in the right direction, I'll leave it to the more senior members to decide on whether to flag the OP or not.

For "full screen capturing" I'm aware there are several solutions, including one for Chrome which saves directly to G Drive.  This is the only noteworthy extension that I will mention simply because it's the only one that's <s>arguably</s> trustworthy, as it's developed and published by the official Google Drive dev team.

For desktop environment, what I would instead use (until an easier and *reputable* solution comes forth) would be a utility that enables you to append images quickly, and can be actionable with automation.  I personally would use something like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php), in combination with [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Note: AHK likely has the capability to accomplish the desired function on it's own, but I've not seen any showcased script for it, and it'd likely not be a viable route to attempt to write it yourself if you aren't already familiar with it.